# Do I need to explicitly setResult to RESULT_CANCELED?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that expects the user to select an item, but the user can instead choose to click the back button without selecting an item.  This "item selecting" activity is started with startActivityForResult().

I was wondering two things.  First, is it sufficient to only setResult(RESULT_OK) when the item is actually selected, i.e., can I rely upon the result not being set to RESULT_OK if I don't set it explicitly?

Second, if this isn't sufficient to rely upon the (uninitialized) result, is it okay to call setResult() multiple times, the first time "initializing" the result to RESULT_CANCELED, and then calling SetResult(RESULT_OK) after the user selects an item and before finishing the activity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities):

> If a child activity fails for any reason (such as crashing), the
>   parent activity will receive a result with the code
>   `RESULT_CANCELED`.

So the result is already `RESULT_CANCELED`, if
you don't explicitly specify the other code. When the user exits your
app via "back" button - you receive `RESULT_CANCELED` as well.

Comment: thanks I saw that in the documentation, which is what prompted the question.  The case I am describing is not that the activity "fails."  It's not clear from the Android API documentation that it is a safe assumption that RESULT_CANCELED is the default, nor is it clear whether or not it is okay to call setResult more than once.

Comment: Another line in documentation, for the onActivityResult method: "The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.". So if you don't return any result, before the user exits activity with back button - the the result is RESULT_CANCELLED.

Comment: About calling setResult more than once - it's really undefined in the doc. So I wouldn't rely on that. Even if it may work for the current APIs, there is no guarantee, that it'll work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)` on each `Activity` and call `finish()`.

In the overrided `OnActivityResult`, do as I have mentioned if the result code is canceled.